# Ionic cordova build android –prod –release only builds a debug apk (app-debug.apk)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, ionic-cli

Since my latest update of the ionic cli (5.4.7), I am no longer able to a release of the code. Running

```
Ionic cordova build android –prod –release builds only a debug apk
```

gives med only the app-debug.apk package, saying:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
44 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 41 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s): 
    /home/kasper/dev/TMNT/arbejd.com/arbejd-app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

I've found a workaround, which is downgrading to 5.4.6 with `npm install -g ionic@5.4.6`, which does give me an `app-release.apk`, but I'd like a better solution.

(Workaround found here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-cordova-build-android-prod-release-builds-only-a-debug-apk/178209)

Comment: try to remove platform & and add it again they build might be work

Comment: @user9088454 Same results unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a ticket with the ionic-team, and it turns out it was an issue with `5.4.7`'s ability to parse parameters (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4229) .. A simple upgrade to 5.4.8 will fix it.

`npm install -g ionic@5.4.8`